# Handling Multiple Characters Input Issue in C++

Tags: c++, character

I am currently working on a C++ quiz program where I have two functions: `ProcessQuestion` and `DisplayQuestions`. The `ProcessQuestion` function is responsible for displaying a question along with its options, prompting the user for an answer, validating the input, and checking if the answer is correct. The `DisplayQuestions` function, on the other hand, orchestrates the display of multiple questions.

However, I am encountering an issue with the user input handling in the `ProcessQuestion` function. When the user enters more than one character for their answer (e.g., "cd"), the program seems to take the first character as the answer for the current question, but then the subsequent character is considered as the answer for the next question without prompting the user again.

```cpp
    void DisplayQuestions()
    {
        system("cls");
        CentredMessage("Quiz Start");

        cout << endl << endl;
        int questionIndices[Q]; // Array to store question indices
        for (int i = 0; i < Q; ++i) {
            questionIndices[i] = i; // Fill array with question indices
        }
        srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); // Seed for random number generation

        // Shuffle question indices using rand()
        for (int i = Q - 1; i > 0; --i) {
            int j = rand() % (i + 1); // Generate a random index
            // Swap questionIndices[i] and questionIndices[j]
            int temp = questionIndices[i];
            questionIndices[i] = questionIndices[j];
            questionIndices[j] = temp;
        }

        // Display questions
        for (int i = 0; i < Q; ++i) {
            ProcessQuestion(questionIndices[i], i + 1);
            cout << endl;
        }

    }


    void ProcessQuestion(int questionIndex, int Qno)
    {
        cout << "Question " << Qno << ": " << Question[questionIndex] << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < O; ++i)
        {
            cout << Option[questionIndex][i] << endl;
        }

        cout << "Enter your answer: ";
        char userAnswer;
        cin >> userAnswer;
        while (!(userAnswer >= 'A' && userAnswer <= 'D') && !(userAnswer >= 'a'))
        {
            cout << "Invalid Option.\n";
            cout << "Enter your answer Again: ";
            cin >> userAnswer;
        }

        userAnswer = toupper(userAnswer);

        string correctAnswer = Correct[questionIndex][0];
        if (userAnswer == correctAnswer[0])
        {
            cout << "Correct answer!" << endl;
            SCORE_ = SCORE_ + 2;
            CorrectAnswerCount_++;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Incorrect answer.";
            cout << " The correct answer is: " << correctAnswer << endl;
            WrongAnswerCount_++;
        }

        system("pause");
        system("cls");
    }
```

when ProcessQuestion is called it display question and that question choices and then ask answer, in answer input if i enter two character forexample cd it take first character as answer of current question then remaining code execute but when ProcessQuestion is called for next question it take next character d as second question answer and didn't ask from user

output

```
Quiz Start


Question 1: What is the purpose of the 'using namespace std;' statement in C++?
A: It imports the standard input/output library
B: It defines the standard namespace for C++ programs
C: It allows you to use functions and objects from the standard namespace without specifying std::
D: It is not a valid C++ statement
Enter your answer: cd
Correct answer!

Question 2: What is the purpose of the 'return' statement in C++?
A: It starts a new function
B: It exits a loop
C: It terminates the program
D: It returns a value from a function
Enter your answer: Correct answer!
```

I attempted to address the issue by adding `cin.ignore(10000000000000000000, '\n');` to clear the input buffer after reading the user's answer.
Initially, this seemed to resolve the problem, but inexplicably, it has stopped working.

```cpp
void ProcesssQuestion(int questionIndex, int Qno) {

    char userAnswer;
    cin >> userAnswer;
    cin.ignore(10000000000000000000, '\n');

}
```

Comment: The behaviour that you are concerned about is normal for all C++ *streams*. It's the reason they are called streams in the first place. Input is **not** a sequence of user interactions, it is a stream of characters. As the answers suggest the way to deal with this is to read the input in the same way as the user enters the input, i.e. one line at a time.

Comment: My Poblem is already Solved by replacing char with string However, I am interested in understanding alternative methods for solving the problem using Cha

Comment: The alternaitve that is sometimes suggested is to use `ignore` to ignore the rest of the characters on that line of input. But that is more complex and less flexible. The sensible way to proceed is to read a string using `getline`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the input from user and storing it into a `char` this datatype is only **one** character hence it only reading one character from input stream at  each input.

I would recommend reading entire input into a `string` like:

```cpp
string user_input;
cin >> user_input;
```

From that you can then check they actually entered anything (not just pressed enter) and if they have use only the first character using:

```cpp
char choice = user_input[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because because **std::cin >> x** will keep on reading the stream until x is in a valid state. So in your case, since x is a char, it will read one character and break. The next **std::cin** will read the next one and so on. If you want to resolve it, use **std::string** to read the entire  line and check if the length is equal to 1. So the type of *userAnwser* should be **std::string**